# can emberjs be used with rails caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ember.js

I have an app that i can create pages using emberjs and using jqueryui drag and drop.

I want these pages to be html pages for google to crawl.

I am just checking that if i goto a page that is created with emberjs. Can i can use rails caching to cache the page so that i can then serve that on my public site to google?

Is this possible?
Does anyone know of any better ways? 
What does the ember core team recommend?

I know there is talk about server side template rendering but has anything been done on this yet ?

thanks a lot
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to use Rails caching to cache the HTML that is generated by a client-side JS app.

There are people who are doing server-side template rendering, however, I haven't seen examples of anyone running Ember server-side yet.

It is an eventual goal of the Ember team to support that scenario, but it's hard to say when that might happen.

Comment: thanks Luke, what would you recommend to do for search engines ?   also do you know how the Ember core team is planning to do this ?

Comment: @RickMoss I don't have any great solutions to recommend for search engines today. Basically, you need to implement pages that crawlers can see at all the URLs you want indexed. Much of Ember will already run fine in a non-browser JS environment. Broadly, the idea is to build on that foundation. Haven't heard of more specific plans.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.

Can i not just save the current body html from my ember app when i change each page.  Then i can just server the raw html on my public app for search engines etc.

This will then use css etc to style properly.

Anyone see any issues with this method ?

thanks